# Where to store service accounts private keys for Google Cloud Platform in Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

As the title states, looking for best practices for storing the private key required by google's api when using service accounts to authenticate requests.

Is it safe to just put them somewhere in the **res** folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, it's safe enough.

It really depends on how important the private key is. If you setup the scope properly, the key should not have any access that it doesn't need. You can always encrypt the private key if that makes you feel safer.

The bottomline is that how safe a solution is depends largely on how enticing it is to get access. If the key simply lets someone access your vacation pictures, then putting it in res folder is safe enough; if the key let's you access nuclear launch codes, then chances are even if you encrypted it and put it on a secure webserver (so the user had to authenticate to the webserver to use the private key) guarded by laser-sharks, it still won't be safe.